# How to implement the file download API function using Java Hessian library

Tags: download, hessian

I am trying to implement the file download api as the Hessian document page mentions:

> file download API
>
> package example;
>
> public interface Download {
>     public InputStream download(String filename, InputStream data);
>   }

But I still could not figure out how to do that?  Why does the download function take an InputStream arguemnt and return another InputStream?

The download method is supposed to read data from a file on the server and send the data out.  What do these two InputStream refer to?

Can someone explain it?  A working example is most appreciated!